# Import xml data in postgresql

Tags: xml, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

i try insert to postgresql table data from XML
This is sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ActualStatuses>
   <ActualStatus ACTSTATID="0" NAME="Not actual" />
   <ActualStatus ACTSTATID="1" NAME="Актуальный" />
</ActualStatuses>
```

To load XMl i use this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION bytea_import(IN p_path text, OUT p_result bytea)
  RETURNS bytea AS
$BODY$
declare
  l_oid oid;
  r record;
begin
  p_result := '';
  select lo_import(p_path) into l_oid;
  for r in ( select data 
             from pg_largeobject 
             where loid = l_oid 
             order by pageno ) loop
    p_result = p_result || r.data;
  end loop;
  perform lo_unlink(l_oid);
end;$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION bytea_import(text)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

For insert value from XML to postgresql table i use thin query:

```
INSERT INTO actualstatuses(
    SELECT
        (xpath('//ActualStatus/@ACTSTATID', myTempTable))[1]::text::bigint AS ACTSTATID,
        (xpath('//ActualStatus/@NAME', myTempTable))[1]::text AS NAME
    FROM
        unnest(xpath('//ActualStatus', convert_from(public.bytea_import('C:/fias/update/AS_ACTSTAT.XML'), 'utf8')::xml)) AS myTempTable);
```

And have parser error:

```
invalid XML content
SQL-status: 2200N
Entity: line 1: parser error : XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document
﻿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><AddressObjectTypes><AddressObjectType
```

But if i remove `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` in XML this work great. I have about 20 XML files, some of is very large. How to get rid of this error?

Comment: Works for me ;) . Please post more details: especially how are you trying to import multiple files.

Comment: @RadekPostołowicz well i create for all files sql query, but i think it can be realized through еру loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   INSERT INTO actualstatuses(
    SELECT
        (xpath('//ActualStatus/@ACTSTATID', myTempTable))[1]::text::bigint AS ACTSTATID,
        (xpath('//ActualStatus/@NAME', myTempTable))[1]::text AS NAME
    FROM
        unnest(xpath('//ActualStatus', replace(convert_from(bytea_import('C:/fias/update/AS_ACTSTAT.XML'), 'utf8'),'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>','')::xml)) AS myTempTable);
```